# Entity framework 6 + sqlite скорость получения данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть контекст данных (его я приводить не буду) и есть у меня такой вот адаптер

```
public class Adapter
{
    FilmsContext _filmsContext;

    public IEnumerable<Film> Getfilms()
    {
        return _filmsContext.Films;
    }
}
```

И вот когда я запрашиваю первый фильм

```
var films = adapter.Getfilms();
var film = films.First();
```

Получение данных длится около 3х секунд. В таблице 4 записи. Запрос SELECT TOP 1... с последующим парсингом выполняется почти мгновенно. Я, конечно, понимаю, что EF накладывает некоторые неудобства в плане быстродействия, но не настолько же. Может, его как то настроить нужно?

Comment: Ну вот и приехали. В вашем др. вопросе я высказывал предположение, что все эти тяжеловесные нахлобучки не для SQLite.

Comment: @Bulson, почему то мне кажется что вы не правы.

Comment: ПРОФИЛИРУЙТЕ. Ну что за херня, вы не привели никакой информации, запрос 3 секунды, угадайте что не так. У меня в sqlite под гиг база, тоже здоровая ORM сверху и не бывает таких долгих запросов.

Comment: А не, все норм, долго выполняется только первый запрос

Comment: @Monk, не ругайтесь вы, мне далеко до вас в плане работы с БД и СУБД. Во первых, как оказалось, это первый запрос выполняется долго (видимо формирование запроса и тд), во вторых мне мало о чем говорит слово "ПРОФИЛИРУЙТЕ". Мне бы алгоритм действий в таких случаях.